# "Functional" const enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function, enums, constants, compile-time

I'm working on the color scheme of a React application (w/ CSS-in-<s>JS</s>TS), and, for convenience, I write the colors using HSL, but, since they are quite a lot, I would like to deliver them to the users as hex to save some unnecessary bytes. I am now faced with two options:

- either I do something like this:

```js
const hsl = (h: number, s: number, l: number) => {
  /* convert to hex */
  return hex;
}

const colors = {
  primary: hsl(205, 1, 0.52)
}
```

but this approach would (1) go against my point of saving bytes and (2) require the colors to be recalculated each and every time,

- or I just write down the HSL values somewhere else, and put hex codes in my code.

I found that the nearest thing to what I want to do are TypeScript's `const enum`s, which replace values at compile time. However, they only store predefined values, and can't – to my knowledge – be used as a function. So, I would need to be able to do something like this:

```js
const enum Hsl (h: number, s: number, l: number) {
  /* convert to hex */
  return hex;
}

const colors = {
  primary: Hsl(205, 1, 0.52)
}
```

which would get compiled to

```
const colors = {
  primary: '#0C9BFF'
};
```

How could I achieve this?

<sup>ᶦˢ ᵗʰᶦˢ ᵉᵛᵉⁿ ᵖᵒˢˢᶦᵇˡᵉˀ</sup>

An alternative I considered was using the first approach and then letting tools like Prepack do some optimizations (pre-evaluating the function and removing it).

Comment: You want to "save bytes"? If your conclusion is that you need to optimize your HSL function, then I'd wager this is a case of incredibly premature optimization. Do you have some reason to believe that your HSL function is a bottleneck?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo he's saying that if the value isn't a constant (but rather a function call) then the render function in react cannot properly determine that the dependency is unchanged. I suspect that this is a misunderstanding on their part, rather than a case of premature optimization (because you can indeed memoize function-called calculations using react hooks). As for "saving bytes", they mean in the minified bundle output, since the hex strings are shorter than the hsl strings.

Comment: Damiano, it sounds like you want to write an npm script that gets called during `prebuild` that takes some HSL strings in one file and generates another file with the equivalent hex strings, then just write the application to import the hex strings, so the HSL strings don't get included in the output bundle, and don't need to be calculated at runtime. This solution will be preferable to trying to get TypeScript to do this for you, since I don't think that's even possible.

Comment: Hmm… I believe I'll go with Prepack, then (which evaluates part of the code and removes unused functions)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some form of caching mechanism.

You first generate a unique id based on the input, e.g.

```
function getId(h: number, s: number, l: number) {
   return String(h) + ',' + String(s) + ',' + String(l)
}
```

and then cache the value as you go:

```
const cache: Record<string, string> = {}
function hsl(h: number, s: number, l: number) {
  const id = getId(h, s, l)
  return cache[id] = /* do your calculation */
}
```

With that, as you fill in your predefined `colors`, the value will be cached and you don't need to re-calculate it.